# How to place list element first without losing other elements c#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List of strings (GUIDS) and I would like to take one and place it in first and bump the other ones down. How can this be done? thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could perform this by using `Remove` (or `RemoveAt`, depending on which information you have access to) and a subsequent `Insert`.

You could also do something like

```
myList.OrderBy(x => x != theFirstNode).ThenBy(x => x.DefaultSortField);
```

Comment: Take note - the second version does not mutate the list in place, whereas the first version does.

Comment: You need either `OrderByDescending` or `OrderBy(x => x != theFirstNode)` since bools order from false to true

Comment: Thanks i Used OrderBy(x => x != theFirstNode)

Answer (score 1):

```
var targetGuid = whateverGuidtoMove;
myGuidList.Remove(targetGuid);
myGuidList.Insert(0, targetGuid);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
oldlist.Remove(value);
oldlist.Insert(0, value);
```